# Ajax onkey event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using onkey event with ajax for searching the customer typed input. I got the list of string of what customer typed. The problem is I am not sure how to display the list of string under the text box where customer can select one from that.

```
<input id="apple" name="apple" type="text" value="" onKeyup="showData(this.value);"/>

function showData(value){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "/search/getResults=" + value,
        data: "",
        success:function(ListOfString){

            $.each(ListOfString, function(index, val)
                    {

                    });


    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input id="apple" name="apple" type="text" value="" onKeyup="showData(this.value);"/>
<div id="result"></div>

(...)
success:function(ListOfString){
    for(var index in ListOfString){
        $("#result").append("<p>"+ListOfString[index]+"</p>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please suggest how I can append this list under my text box?

Comment: Its displaying under the text box as like that in the page but can't able to select from the list. Thanks anyway for your help. Will try to figure out from here.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution-you don't:) You are trying to do a autosuggest, for that I would preffer an autoutocomplete, like http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ .

But if you want to do it manually:

```
<input id="apple" name="apple" type="text" value="" onKeyup="showData(this.value);"/>
<div id="apply-suggestions"></div>
<script>
...
function showSugestions(suggestions){

var container = $('#apply-suggestions').empty();
$.each(suggestions, function(suggestion){
  $('<div></div>',{class: 'suggestion-item'}).text(suggestion).appendTo(container);
});
}

$('#suggestions > .suggestion-item').on('click',function(){
 console.log('Do something with it...');
});
```

Comment: Remebmer to add proper css styles to suggestions:)